# Why does melt produce a warning when one passes a list to measure.vars?

Tags: r, data.table

I am just wondering why does `melt` throw this warning when I pass a defined list to `measure.vars` arg?

```r
ny = 3
times = 1990L + 10 * (seq_len(ny)-1)
measure_vars_long = c('gdppc', 'lifexp')
measure_vars_wide = list(measure_var1 = paste0('gdppc_', times[-3]),
                         measure_var2 = paste0('lifexp_', times))


DT = data.table::data.table(
    country = c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
    gdppc_1990 = c(121782.304323278, 126794.359297492, 150476.795178838),
    gdppc_2000 = c(118858.692678623, 143942.932505161, 166981.9295872),
    lifexp_1990 = c(54.4529938697815, 93.5958937462419, 92.9653832130134),
    lifexp_2000 = c(88.843795270659, 77.9958764929324, 96.4652526797727),
    lifexp_2010 = c(81.6346854623407, 90.6221343390644, 63.0786676099524)
)

melt(DT,
     idvars = 'country',
     measure = measure_vars_wide, #with(measure_vars_wide, list(measure_var1, measure_var2))
     variable.name = 'year',
     value.name = c('gdppc', 'lifexp'))

  country year measure_var1 measure_var2
1:      c1    1     121782.3     54.45299
2:      c2    1     126794.4     93.59589
3:      c3    1     150476.8     92.96538
4:      c1    2     118858.7     88.84380
5:      c2    2     143942.9     77.99588
6:      c3    2     166981.9     96.46525
7:      c1    3           NA     81.63469
8:      c2    3           NA     90.62213
9:      c3    3           NA     63.07867
```

Warning message:
'value.name' provided in both 'measure.vars' and 'value.name argument'; value provided in 'measure.vars' is given precedence.

However, this works:

```r
melt(DT,
     idvars = 'country',
     measure = with(measure_vars_wide, list(measure_var1, measure_var2)),
     variable.name = 'year',
     value.name = c('gdppc', 'lifexp'))

  country year    gdppc   lifexp
1:      c1    1 121782.3 54.45299
2:      c2    1 126794.4 93.59589
3:      c3    1 150476.8 92.96538
4:      c1    2 118858.7 88.84380
5:      c2    2 143942.9 77.99588
6:      c3    2 166981.9 96.46525
7:      c1    3       NA 81.63469
8:      c2    3       NA 90.62213
9:      c3    3       NA 63.07867
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading `?data.table::melt`, we see that

```
measure.vars: Measure variables for 'melt'ing. Can be missing, vector,
          list, or pattern-based.
    ...
          For convenience/clarity in the case of multiple 'melt'ed
          columns, resulting column names can be supplied as names to
          the elements 'measure.vars' (in the 'list' and 'patterns'
          usages). See also 'Examples'.

value.name: name for the molten data values column(s). ...
                                            ... though note well that
          the names provided in 'measure.vars' take precedence.
```

This means that names in `measure.vars` can be used in place of `value.name`.

To confirm that, we can use the named-list variant and remove the `value.name` and see that the new column names are indeed from `names(measure_vars_wide)`:

```r
melt(DT,
     idvars = 'country',
     measure = measure_vars_wide,
     variable.name = 'year')
#    country   year measure_var1 measure_var2
#     <char> <fctr>        <num>        <num>
# 1:      c1      1     121782.3     54.45299
# 2:      c2      1     126794.4     93.59589
# 3:      c3      1     150476.8     92.96538
# 4:      c1      2     118858.7     88.84380
# 5:      c2      2     143942.9     77.99588
# 6:      c3      2     166981.9     96.46525
# 7:      c1      3           NA     81.63469
# 8:      c2      3           NA     90.62213
# 9:      c3      3           NA     63.07867
```

So you can use the named list exclusive, using `'gdppc'` and `'lifexp'` as the list's names instead, and remove the `value.name=` argument, and get the desired effect without any `warning`s.

Why does it behave differently in your second code? Because your `with(., list(.))` is returning an unnamed list:

```r
with(measure_vars_wide, list(measure_var1, measure_var2))
# [[1]]
# [1] "gdppc_1990" "gdppc_2000"
# [[2]]
# [1] "lifexp_1990" "lifexp_2000" "lifexp_2010"
```

In the end, I think you can stick with the `with(...)` code, or change your code to be:

```r
measure_vars_wide = list(gdppc = paste0('gdppc_', times[-3]),
                         lifexp = paste0('lifexp_', times))

melt(DT,
     idvars = 'country',
     measure = measure_vars_wide,
     variable.name = 'year')
#    country   year    gdppc   lifexp
#     <char> <fctr>    <num>    <num>
# 1:      c1      1 121782.3 54.45299
# 2:      c2      1 126794.4 93.59589
# 3:      c3      1 150476.8 92.96538
# 4:      c1      2 118858.7 88.84380
# 5:      c2      2 143942.9 77.99588
# 6:      c3      2 166981.9 96.46525
# 7:      c1      3       NA 81.63469
# 8:      c2      3       NA 90.62213
# 9:      c3      3       NA 63.07867
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Now I see why `measure.vars` needs to get a named list (names being the new names for the long-form) that way. But, I still think the first code should work without warning, better if `value.name` takes precedence over measure.vars (the names of the named list).

Comment: I see your point, but I disagree: if you are comfortable with using named arguments to `measure.vars` (whether or not you continue reading the help page that says *"the names provided in 'measure.vars' take precedence"*), if you accidentally give a named list as an argument (perhaps it was created programmatically, names not intended), then having a warning is a cue to *where* the problem is. Without the warning, consider how difficult it may be to troubleshoot incorrect names.

Comment: Of course, that is the point. Passing a named list is also equally good and straightforward. However, in case of the list being not named properly, I am not saying the warning should not be invoked. My point is that it would be better to pass the names of the new variables explicitly in `value.name` as opposed to relying on the names of the list in `measure.vars`.  I personally would prefer that.

Comment: As for your previous comment on `value.name`, to be honest ... I didn't know about named-`measure.vars` until answering this question (this is one way I learn).

Comment: I am glad you learn from answering this question. Btw, I came to this question because I was recently comparing `stats::reshape` with `data.table`'s reshape. I happen to like more the stats' reshape but only has one weakness; it does not work when the number of years is not equal in all measures like in the above example, gdppc has two years while lifexp has three.